# What other option do I have to HTML 5 video?

Tags: android, ios, html5-video

I've been trying to make a html5 video to work in IOS and Android with

- Autoplay
- Loop
- No controls

I found a lot of codes out there and tried them all but I can't get it working

This is the best I've got:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" controls="" id="video" loop="true" style="display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <source src="timelapse_panoramic_fin_5.webm" type="video/webm" /> 
    <source src="timelapse_panoramic_fin_5.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> 
    <source src="timelapse-panoramic-fin_5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I think that it will be very hard to get this working properly.  **What other option do I have to HTML 5 video?**

Answer (score 1):

Use webview.

```
 WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
 String html="you html code for video";
 webView.loadData(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already experienced, video playout across different platforms and browsers can be hard. I would definitely recommend to use a player framework, like [Video.js](http://videojs.com/), or in context of adaptive streaming, [Bitmovin player](https://www.bitmovin.com/), etc. They can make your life much more easy.